# Mysql Question: Ubuntu Server died. I have access to the /var/lib/mysql files from backup... How to get them back up on another machine?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Ok an internal Ubuntu(11.04) box died the other day. We were using it as a webserver and it had a load of mysql databases on it.

I have access to all the files from the /var/lib/mysql dir but I can't figure out how to get them back up and running on another machine. I've tried copying them into a windows mysql install and I can see all the databases in phpmyadmin but no tables.

I've also tried changing the data dir on a mysql install on another ubuntu box (I also changed the apparmor settings) but have had no joy so far...

I just want to get them up to do a data dump... Any links/pointers greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Where your tables innodb or myisam?

Answer (score 3):

If ServerA is the old Webserver and ServerB is the new machine you want to run MySQL on

**Step 1**

Install the same version exact version of MySQL you had on ServerA to ServerB

**Step 2**

Copy /etc/my.cnf from ServerA and put it /etc on ServerB

**Step 3**

scp /var/lib/mysql from ServerA to same location on ServerB

**Step 4**

service mysql start

Please let us know what happens !!!

Comment: You may try running mysql_upgrade.